# how to create a collection or array of my custom objects

Tags: java, collections

I have a class called anItem and it allows me to model variables into an object.

I have many of these objects and i want to put them into a colection. What is the class code for the collection?

Here is what i have:

```
package com.rest.myproject;

public class anItem 
{
    String name;
    String age;     
    public anItem()
    {
        super();
    }       
    //methods
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }       
    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        this.name=newName;
    }    
    public String getAge() 
    {
        return this.age;
    }   
    public void setAge(String newAge)
    {
        this.age=newAge;
    }    
}

Public class aCollectionOfItems 
{
    anItem[] item; ->should I create a array of items to add and remove from?
    public aCollection()
    {
        super();
    }       
    //How do I add aItem to my collection, create an array of items?    
}
```

Comment: You can use ArrayList<anItem> list= new ArrayList<>(); instead of array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `List` to hold your items.

```
public class Item {

    private String name;
    private String age;

    //methods
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}

public class CollectionOfItems {

    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok great  - should i use a List or an ArrayList<aItem>?

Comment: What i mean is i just thought of this just as you posted but what i had was ArrayList<aItem> myCollection; which allows me to add to that arrayList. Why do you declare your List that way and not as above?

Comment: @Fearghal - A `List` is a general term (i.e. `interface`). Several classes implement `List` including `ArrayList` as I have used here.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class CollectionOfItems {
        int size = 10; //any size that is required.
        private final Item[] item;
        public aCollection(){
            super();
            item = new Item[size];
        }
    }
```

Java Collections can also be used to hold the items, as a replacement for Arrays.

Comment: Hi thx for yout help. I marked the above as answer as it doesnt depend on knowing size of collection at start 'size' and it was submitted first.  thx a mill for your help tho, the code is good!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest on reading through Oracle's documentation / tutorial of Java collections:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

A few brief examples:

- [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) - This is a list of objects, stored as an array.
  Useful form quick ransom access
- [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) - This is also a list. Useful if you don't know the size of the list ahead of time, but it's
  not efficient for random access
- [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) - This is a set. Only one of each items is allowed. Items are compared using hashCode() and equals().
- [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) - This is also a set. Items are sorted, so you can
  iterate them in some order.
- [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) - This is a key/value collection.
  For example HashMap is will store/retrieve
- [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) - This is also key/value store. Items are sorted.